# Can't seem to translate the MySQL query to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have been trying to translate the following MySQL query into Laravel Query Builder. Could anyone suggest how to get this working?

```
SELECT
orders.id AS order_id,
COUNT(products.id) AS count
FROM
order_product
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
LEFT JOIN products ON order_product.product_id = products.id
WHERE
orders.user_id = 2
GROUP BY
orders.id
```

Here is my current code:

```
public static function getProductsCount($userId = null)
{
    if (!is_numeric($userId)) {
        return false;
    }
    DB::table('order_product')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
        ->join('products', 'order_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        #->select('orders.id AS orders_id')
        ->where('orders.user_id', '=', $userId)
        ->distinct('products.id')
        ->groupBy('orders.id')
        ->count('products.id');
}
```

In contrast to the query I want to execute, I get the following:

```
select count(distinct `products`.`id`) as aggregate from `order_product` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = `order_product`.`order_id` inner join `products` on `order_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where `orders`.`user_id` = ? group by `orders`.`id`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If all else fails, you can just use a raw query. Nothing states that you need to use the query builder.

Comment: True but I prefer to use Query Builder (for it's SQL Injection protection and  because I want to understand).

Comment: you are using ->join instead of ->leftJoin in your illuminate query

Comment: @michael quite right. I corrected this and it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` method overrides the specified `select` columns temporarily, because it runs an aggregate function on the database. To avoid that you can just use the select as it is defined in your query. Also as @michael pointed out in the comment you should be using `leftJoin` instead of `join`. The following will generate the exact query you posted:

```
DB::table('order_product')
        ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
        ->leftJoin('products', 'order_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('orders.id AS orders_id', 'COUNT(products.id) AS count')
        ->where('orders.user_id', '=', $userId)
        ->groupBy('orders.id')
        ->get();
```